# How to get current active theme in magento 2.0

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I am getting trouble with Magento 2.0. I have to use current active theme name which I got in magento 1.x versions like:
"Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName()"
But I didn't get any alternate for Magento 2.0. Please suggest me what model or function should I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:
Follwing class will need to have dependency:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
\Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProviderInterface
```

Use this method to get data for current theme:

```
public function getTheme()
{
    $themeId = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::XML_PATH_THEME_ID,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    );

    /** @var $theme \Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface */
    $theme = $this->_themeProvider->getThemeById($themeId);

    return $theme->getData();
}
```

Comment: If you get `null` on `$theme` use `\Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProvider` instead `\Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProviderInterface`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following example to get the current active theme in Magento 2.0:

```
use Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface;

$theme = $this->_design->getDesignTheme()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can get and check current Theme like  -

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface');

    if($appState->getDesignTheme()->getCode()=='Mgs/mgsmobile') {
        var_dump('Theme is active');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First injection interface Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ResolverInterface
in construct

```
/** @var ThemeInterface $theme */
$theme = $this->themeResolver->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

getSingleton is depreciated from magento 2, instead of this

```
$object_manager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/66167788899/magento-2-replacements-for-getmodel-and